# ¿Porque al hacer un target de la etiqueta name, recibo el error "event is undefined"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, nodejs, ejs

Estoy haciendo un projecto con nodejs, express, JQuery, EJS y mongoDB. El problema es que estoy tratando de validar un formlulario en el cual estoy recorriendo los inputs de un formlulario y añadiendole un evento keyUp para que al escribir me retorne otra funccion cuyo trabajo es hacer un target de la etiqueta del input donde se escribe, pero me retorna el error: "event is undefined".

HTML:

```
<label class="form-label">Carnet:</label>
<input type="text" name="nombreCarnet" id="Carnet" class="form-control" required="required" maxlength="6">
<p class="error" id="nombreCarnetError"></p>
<label class="form-label">Nombre:</label>
<input type="text" name="nombreCol" id="nombreCol" class="form-control" required="required"
maxlength="15">
<p class="error" id="nombreColError"></p>
<label class="form-label">Apellido:</label>
<input type="text" name="apellidoCol" id="apellidoCol" class="form-control" required="required" maxlength="15">
<p class="error" id="apellidoColError"></p>
```

CODIGO:

```
function validarFormulario(event){
    let tar = event.target.name;
    console.log(tar);
}

$(inputs).each(function(){
    $(this).keyup(function(){
       validarFormulario()
    })
})
```

IMAGEN DEL ERROR:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es simple.

La función `validarFormulario` tiene un parámetro llamado `evento`.

Cuando tu llamas la función no lo pasas:

```
validarFormulario()
```

Por eso tiene como valor `undefined`.

Comment: Hola @Mateo. Solo debo de pasarle el evento a la funccion? algo como esto; "validarFormulario(evento)" ?

Comment: @JulioAndré Exacto.

Comment: Gracias Mateo. Funciono como tu dices!.